# Refresh parent window from child window when child is HTTPS and parent is HTTP

Tags: javascript

Like the title says, i have a parent window with button that opens a child window for login under https. i found a lot of examples and they all work great when the child window is not HTTPS. like this example:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            if (loginSuccess)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(UpdatePanel1, typeof(UpdatePanel), "Redirect", "window.close();window.opener.location.reload(true);", true);   
            }


    }
```

Works great when child is **http**
Not Working when child is **https**

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible due to cross-domain scripting restrictions and HTTP->HTTPS is considered cross domain. You may take a look at the [following article](http://blog.infoentropy.com/Use_IFRAME_access_windowopener_HTTPS_popup_a_HTTP_page) for a workaround using an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You [can't access the objects you need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) across origins.

(And if this was possible, then data could leak in and out of the secure page from the other window, rendering the security rather less useful).

If you want security, enter HTTP before opening any new windows and don't leave it.